# are all the variables independent of each other

Tags: probability, statistics, random, independence

Consider three random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, then does that mean that $X$ and $Z$ are independent too?

Comment: No. You could even have $X=Z$.

Comment: Indeed any borel function of $X$ is a counterexample: $Z=f(X)$

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As drhab pointed out in a comment, the premises are consistent with $X=Z$, in which case $X$ and $Z$ will generally not be independent.